# two send functions, only sending one

Tags: c

I'm trying to send two send functions to PIC, and read it through the wireshark.

```
send(StreamSock, tbfr1, tlen1, 0);
DelayMsec(20000);
send(StreamSock, tbfr2, tlen2, 0);
```

tbfr1 is 90 bytes, tbfr2 is 584 bytes.

But the second send function is not sent.

If I put only either one function, they are sent. But If two send functions only send the first one.

Does anyone know the issue with this?

Thanks

Comment: Google "nagle algorithm".

Comment: so it seems like it's a congestion problem?

Comment: No. It seems like it's the Nagle algorithm, which delays sends so it can combine them with future sens.

Comment: but how can there be a delay when it's not even coming through??

Comment: The Nagle algorithm delays SENDING the packet.

Comment: so does that mean the packet will be received sooner or later?

Comment: Yes. It shouldn't be delayed very long, just a large fraction of a second.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm confused. The data from the second send function is not sent or received. It is completely missing. I can wait for 1 minute, and it don't see it in the wireshark. So I don't think it's delayed. The second send function is not sent at all...